# Better phrase for "unique up to cyclic permutation"

Tags: permutations, terminology

I have seen statements of the form: "such-and-such is characterized by a 4-tuple, which is unique up to cyclic permutations." The intended meaning is that we don't want to count the 4-tuples $(x,y,z,w)$ and $(w,x,y,z)$ as really *different* for our purposes, whereas $(w,z,x,y)$ *is* different. The idea is that each 4-tuple could be represented up to 4 different ways (or fewer, in cases such as $(x,y,x,y)$ or $(x,x,x,x)$).

Someone pointed out to me, though, the phrase doesn't really say what we want it to say. The permutation that changes $(w,x,y,z)$ to $(w,z,x,y)$ is, in fact, a cyclic permutation - of three of the elements. Indeed, the permutation that turns $(w,x,y,z)$ into $(y,w,z,x)$ is a 4-cycle, that just happens to go in a different order than the order of the 4-tuple.

Is there a more precise way of saying what is meant here than "unique up to cyclic permutation", that isn't also horribly clunky? Or is there a good argument for why "unique up to cyclic permutation" really does mean what I want it to mean?

I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Your question does make sense, but I don't think there is a neat answer. Everyone knows what is intended when you say "unique up to a cyclic permutation" in this context and saying something different would likely be more misleading than using the standard jargon. If you really think it matters, then I'd recommend a footnote to explain exactly what is meant.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with "unique up to cyclic permutation" and I use it all the time. All you have to do is when you write that phrase, you define exactly what you mean, for example: a cyclic permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,....,n\}$ is any permutation defined by addition modulo $n$ of some integer $k$. In general, all you have to do is to specify a cyclic permutation *of the entire index set of your $n$-tuple*.

Comment: If it helps you accept this possibly flawed terminology, note that in the usual meaning the composition of two cyclic permutations is again a cyclic permutation, but in your someone-pointed-out meaning that is no longer true; in other words, the usual meaning puts an equivalence relation on the set of 4-tuples, while the modified meaning does not.

Comment: So, I'm not actually bothered by this terminology; I was just asking for the sake of clarity about it. All of these comments make great sense. If any of you wants to post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it, and then this wouldn't be sitting in the "unanswered" list.